# Mobx Observer not working as expected when using FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

When trying to create a Listview of items inside the body of a Scaffold, I am unable to update the displaying of the amount of items in that list in another place (Appbar) with mobx (version: 0.3.5) and flutter_mobx (version: 0.3.0+1).

I already tried to solve this with the Provider package (3.0.0+1), but this didn't work out as well, so I guess I am missing something about the nature of FutureBuilder and Flutter's build-process.

```
// the mobx-store
ItemTracker itemTracker = ItemTracker();

class StartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  StartPageState createState() => StartPageState();
}

class StartPageState extends State<StartPage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
// this Observer doesn't update
          leading: Observer(
              builder: (_) => Text('Items: ' + itemTracker.amount.toString())),
          title: Text('MyApp',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[50],
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              )),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
                future: ApiService.getOffers(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Offer>> snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    default:
                      return snapshot.hasError
                          ? Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}')
                          : _createOfferList(context, snapshot);
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
  Widget _createOfferList(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
// after receiving the response, the amount of items should get written to 
// itemTracker.amount - the Observer-part should be rerendered, but it won't
    itemTracker.updateAmount(snapshot.data.length);
    print(snapshot.data.length.toString());
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        primary: false,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Image.asset(snapshot.data[index].image),
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].description ?? ''),
                isThreeLine: true,
                trailing: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, right: 4.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.explore,
                    color: Colors.green[200],
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            OfferDetailPage(snapshot.data[index]))),
              ));
        });
  }
}
```

so the upper part of the code fetches the items from `ApiService.getOffers` and then calls the `_createOfferList` to build the Listview. 
Inside this method, the `itemTracker`-instance's mobx-observable `amount` gets updated by the mobx-action `updateAmount(int newValue)` with the length of the snapshot's data-list.
In the `Scaffold` above, I'm then using an `Observer` to track and display the amount of items.
Aside from the amount not getting updated, the App works as expected and the List gets rendered. If I navigate forth and back in the app, the amount of list-items gets displayed correctly, but it never happens on the initial page-load.

*edit*: just as a side-note: I didn't show off the `ItemTracker` class-definition and the corresponding generated class, since all it does is use an observable-annotation for the `amount`-member and an action-annotation for the method that just takes an int-parameter and writes it to `this.amount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today i managed to implement a workaround for my problem by introducing a class-member holding the items, and react on receiving them by calling `itemTracker.updateAmount()` inside an `initState()`-method.

```
class OfferPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List<Offer>> data = ApiService.getOffers();
  OfferPageState createState() => OfferPageState();
}

class OfferPageState extends State<OfferPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.data.then((offers) => itemTracker.updateAmount(offers.length));
    super.initState();
  }
// ...

//the new Scaffold body part
body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder(
// no longer create a request, but instead use the existing request's future
                future: widget.data,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    default:
                      return _createOfferList(context, snapshot);
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
```

The `_createOfferList`-method remains exactly the same albeit without the call to `updateAmount()`, since this part is now handled inside `initState()`.